# 스푼 in a recipe: tablespoons or teaspoons?

Tags: food

When following a Korean recipe, does 스푼 refer to a specific unit of measurement like a teaspoon or just a generic spoon?

I was cooking some Samyang spicy chicken ramen, and came across instructions saying to leave behind "8스푼" (eight spoons) of water. I interpreted 스푼 to mean teaspoon and not tablespoon, which resulted in a highly concentrated broth. Is there a special Korean spoon one would use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about 스푼.  They probably meant the size of a 밥숟가락, which is not a precise unit but probably a bit less than a tablespoon.

In recipes, teaspoon and tablespoon are written as 작은술 and 큰술, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I think "스푼" means a tablespoon and "티스푼" means a teaspoon. I know there is no such a strict criteria about "스푼" if there is no special mention.